# Nested word automatons

Tags: finite-automata

At the moment I'm trying to understand nested word automatons but I don't get the point quiet right. Let's say I have the alphabet $\Sigma = \{c,r\}$ and I want ot recoginize the  languge $\mathcal{L} = \{ \langle  c^n r\rangle^n \}$. On slide 14 of [this](https://swt.informatik.uni-freiburg.de/teaching/SS2012/AutomataTheory/Resources/Slides/nestedwordautomata-seminarslides-christianschilling.pdf) presentation I found the following automaton which should recognize $\mathcal{L}$.

[image]

After reading the last $\langle c$ the automaton is is state $(q_1,p_1)$ and, since $\delta_r: Q \times P \times \Sigma \rightarrow  Q$, after reading the first $r\rangle$ it switches to $(q_2)$. So how does the automaton keep track of reading the same ammount of $\langle c$ and $r\rangle$? Do we have to keep the hierarchical state in mind for each call symbol? If so wouldn't we need a stack again for that?

Comment: Thank you so much for creating the TAGs!

Answer (score 2):

Please note that the input to a nested word automaton is nested words instead of the usual words.

**A nested word** $n$ over $\Sigma$ is a pair $(a_1\cdots a_l; \leadsto)$, where $a_i\in\Sigma$ and $\leadsto$ is a matching relation of length $l$. Note that if there is no pending call nor pending returns (in which case $\leadsto$ is said to be **well-matched**), then the number of the calls and the number of returns are equal by the definition of a matching relation. This is the case when you use $\{ \langle  c, r\rangle\}$ as the alphabet of $L$ to represent the nested words.

What the nested word automaton in the question does mostly is, indeed, to check that all $\langle c$'s happens before $r\rangle$'s.

You are encouraged to read the seminal paper [*Adding Nesting Structure to Words*](http://www.cis.upenn.edu/~alur/Jacm09.pdf) by Rajeev Alur and P. Madhusudan. You might be delighted to find it is pretty easy to read, especially the relevant section 3.1.

Comment: I did read that. Maybe let's do an example. Let's consider the word $w = \langle c\langle c\langle cr\rangle r\rangle r\rangle$. The run, as explained in that paper, would look like this for the first 3 symbols: $q_0q_1q_1q_1$ and $p_0p_0p_1p_1$. But what is next now? $\delta_r$ only gives us a $q$ so how does the $p$ series continue?

Comment: From the example of the paper: For example, in state $q_1$, while processing a call, the hierarchical state on the nestingedge is $p_1$, and the new linear state is $q_0$/$q_1$ depending on whether the call is labeled $1$/$0$. I do not understand this... How can I read $\langle 1$ in $q_1$?